# How do you call a function which name is a variable?

Tags: function, syntax, raku

I am trying to use this syntax to call a function `"$name"()`. I know this works for methods, but I do not if there is a way to do it with functions from a module.

I have tried this => `sub b(){say "b";}; "b"();`, but it does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@sena_kun has answerd me via [Perl6 IRC channel](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2019-07-04#l192), and it looks like the correct syntax would be: `sub b(){say "best" }; ::('&b')();`.

As you can see that looks like "magic", so instead of that, @sena_kun has told me this more comprehensible way: `sub a {1.say}; sub b {2.say}; my @a = &a, &b; for @a -> &f { &f()}`

Comment: `::(...)` is not magic -- all it does is look up the contained symbol at runtime (instead of at compile time), which the example then calls as a subroutine with `()`. The more "comprehensible" way is not at all the same -- it requires the symbols to be known at compile time.

Comment: You can also use `&::('b')`